# como aplicar una función inversa en haskell

Tags: funciones, haskell, programación-funcional, function

buenas estoy intentando hacer un map con la peculiaridad que en vez de aplicarle la función al conjunto dado, quiero que este le aplica la función inversa.ç

es decir  si coloco inversa (+1) [2,3,4]  estas debiera devolverme  [1,2,3], hasta ahora solo he logrado  programar lo siguiente:

```
inverso _ [] = []
inverso f (x:xs) = f x : inverso f xs
```

claro esta que esta es la funcion map pero como otro nombre, no tengo la menor idea de como aplicar la función inversa 
he buscaso informacion sobre como hacer eso y no he encontrado nada que sea util sera que me puede decir que tengo que hacer aqui

PD: me habian comentado que podia poner (-f) y haskel entendia que estaba buscando la funcion inverda sera que me peuden confirmar si eso es verdad y de lo contrario ayudarme a llegar a una solucion

Comment: No sé si entiendo a lo que te refieres por función *inversa*. Si tenemos una función `f`, su función *inversa* `g` es aquella tan que su composición sea la *identidad*: `g . f ≡ id`. Por definición, no toda función tiene inversa (por ejemplo: `f x = 1`).

Comment: no claro eso lo se,  en este caso particular toda función que se le pase a mi función de haskell tiene inversa, solo quiero saber si existe una forma simple de hacer eso, de lo contrario tendré que hablar con mi profesor para ver que me estoy obviando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demos por supuesto que la función es *biyectiva* (para que tenga *inversa*). Como no se conoce su definición, no se puede crear su función inversa de modo analítico.

Para obtener la función inversa tenemos que hacerlo por fuerza bruta, aplicando la función sobre todo el dominio para obtener así las referencias inversas.

Por simplificar, tomaremos como dominio el de los *números naturales* (`[1..]`):

```
inversa :: (Integer -> Integer) -> (Integer -> Integer)
inversa f = \x -> head $ [i | i <- [1..], f i == x]
```

Se puede optimizar un poco creando una lista con todos los valores calculados:

```
inversa :: (Integer -> Integer) -> (Integer -> Integer)
inversa f = \x -> head $ [i | (i, fx) <- xs, fx == x]
  where xs = [(i, f i) | i <- [1..]]
```

Ejemplos de uso:

```
map (inversa (+3)) [4,7,10]  ---> [1,4,7]
map (inversa (`div`2)) [4,8,12]  ---> [8,16,24]
map (inversa (\x -> 4*x+1)) [5,9,21]  ---> [1,2,5]
```

Pero falla cuando la aplicamos a un valor que no pertenece al dominio de la función inversa. Los siguientes ejemplos NO FUNCIONAN:

```
inversa (+3) 2
inversa (`div`2) 7
inversa (\x -> 4*x+1) 2
```

Por completitud, podemos crear una versión más general de función inversa:

```
inversaEn :: (Eq b) => [a] -> (a -> b) -> (b -> a)
inversaEn dom f = \x -> head $ [i | (i, fx) <- xs, fx == x]
      where xs = [(i, f i) | i <- dom]
```

Y se aplicaría así:

```
-- dominios
naturales = [1..]
enteros = concat [[a,b] | (a,b) <- zip [0,-1..] [1..]]

-- equivalente a la anterior
inversa :: (Integer -> Integer) -> (Integer -> Integer)
inversa = inversaEn naturales

-- una inversa más amplia
inversaZ :: (Integer -> Integer) -> (Integer -> Integer)
inversaZ = inversaEn enteros

-- esta inversa ya está definida para más casos
inversaZ (+3) 2
inversaZ (\x -> 4*x+1) (-3)
```